# eCharts xAxis axisPointer handle click event

Tags: echarts

I am looking for a way to register a click event on  axisPointer. User should be able to click on xAxis axisPointer and we should be able to call a function. When you click on the highlighted part, want to move the coordinates of that point. I took the pattern from the link below. [Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-tooltip-touch&version=5.3.3) and [my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWuPC.png)